# SEO friendly url in yii 1.1

Tags: yii, friendly-url, yii-url-manager

i want only SanphamController to have from this:

mySite/sanpham/chitiet/slug/nuoc-hoa-phap-vuiton.html

to

mySite/nuoc-hoa-phap-vuiton.html

i have dealed it but all other Controller (CartController,etc,..) in my site not run anymore, it think the controller is an item in SanPhamController.

This is my code

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

In main/config.php:

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'rules' => array(
            '/'=>'site/index',
            '<view:(gioi-thieu|huong-dan|hinh-thuc-thanh-toan|dieu-khoan-dich-vu|chinh-sach-dich-vu)>' => 'site/page',
            '<action:(lienhe|thanhtoan|dangnhap|dangky|dangxuat)>' => 'site/<action>',
            'danh-muc/<slug:.*>'=>'sanpham/danhmuc',
            'thuong-hieu/<slug:.*>'=>'sanpham/thuonghieu',
            'tim-kiem/<slug:.*>'=>'sanpham/timkiem',
            '<slug:.*>' => 'sanpham/chitiet',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/chitiet',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'urlSuffix' => '.html',
        'showScriptName' => false,
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this rule at the top of url manager array:

```
"nuoc-hoa-phap-vuiton"=>"sanpham/chitiet/slug/nuoc-hoa-phap-vuiton"
```

Comment: nuoc-hoa-phap-vuiton is only a Model item in the ActionChitiet. i have done that, but it confuse with other controller name.

example: "mySite/cart/index" not working anymore. 

how can i run the yii default rule before checking it is a item in the sanpham/chitiet or not?

Comment: You can put that rule at the end of url rules or at the end of user-define url rules(before yii default rules).